# meshlab 2016 compilation issue - Unable to find shaders directory

Tags: c++, qt, meshlab

We tried to install **meshlab 2016** on linux by compiling it from the source code. In the end, we managed to finish but with a notice saying

> Unable to find shaders directory; No shaders will be loaded

Does anyone have a clue to solve this?

Also, while compiling, it seems that all the relative links for external libs (**lib3ds.a** etc) went mad, were forced to add exact path in the files to solve this. Does anyone have a solution for this?

The compilation is done using

> QT 4.2.0 Based on Qt 5.7.1 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64
>   bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating executable/shared libraries in a manually created folder? `shaders` folder is present in `meshlab/src/distrib/` and by default executable and shared libraries will be copied to that location.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer -- srry but I didn't react earlier as I didn't get any notice from the website.

Comment: It seems that after compilation, I have another folder named meshlab-2016.12/ and but the shaders are in the original meshlab/src. In the end, we copied all the shaders information to meshlab-2016.12/build-meshlab_full-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Release/distrib and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little bit more logs ? I am not sure about your problem, but it looks similar to an issue I met with "Shadow build" compilation configuration option ([this issue is described there](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/34))

Once compiled, external libs are expected to be in `meshlab/src/external/lib/linux-g++`. If you have checked "Shadow build" in "Projects", you find them in `meshlab/src/build-external-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/lib/linux-g++`. If you did not check on "Shadow build", you don't face the issue.

The problem comes from line 153 in meshlab.pro file :

`linux-g++:LIBS += -L../external/lib/linux-g++ -ljhead -L../distrib -lcommon -lGLU`

It should be changed to :

`linux-g++:LIBS += -L../../src/external/lib/linux-g++ -ljhead -L../distrib -lcommon -lGLU`

Other "pro" file should be also changed. See the link provided for details.